# Powershell WMI Win32_LogicalDisk - Filtering on FreeSpace

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I have a bigger script that sends emails when disk of various computer is under 20%.  Now I have one computer that is under 20%, but has 40 GB, so I want to add a second filter to only send the email when the FreeSpace < 10 GB.

I can't get the additional filter to work, even though it seems like what I'm doing is logical.

```
[decimal]$thresholdPercentFree = 20
[decimal]$thresholdFreespaceGB = 10 

Write-Host "TEST1" 
 Get-WMIObject  -ComputerName $computers Win32_LogicalDisk `
| select __SERVER, DriveType, VolumeName, Name, @{n='Size (Gb)' ;e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.size/1gb)}},@{n='FreeSpace (Gb)';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}}, @{n='PercentFree';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.freespace/$_.size*100)}} `
| Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and [decimal]$_.PercentFree -lt [decimal]$thresholdPercentFree } 

Write-Host "TEST2" 
 Get-WMIObject  -ComputerName $computers Win32_LogicalDisk `
| select __SERVER, DriveType, VolumeName, Name, @{n='Size (Gb)' ;e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.size/1gb)}},@{n='FreeSpace (Gb)';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}}, @{n='PercentFree';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.freespace/$_.size*100)}} `
| Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and [decimal]$_.PercentFree -lt [decimal]$thresholdPercentFree -and [decimal]($_.FreeSpace/1gb) -lt $thresholdFreespaceGB}
```

Output: The desire is that Test2 will not show any servers because the FreeSpace > 10.

```
TEST1
__SERVER       : MyServerName
DriveType      : 3
VolumeName     : 
Name           : C:
Size (Gb)      : 249.66
FreeSpace (Gb) : 46.18
PercentFree    : 18.50

TEST2
__SERVER       : MyServerName
DriveType      : 3
VolumeName     : 
Name           : C:
Size (Gb)      : 249.66
FreeSpace (Gb) : 46.18
PercentFree    : 18.50
```

Comment: FreeSpace is not a property in your where-object. He property is now 'freespace (gb)'

Comment: Thanks, I guess I thought the prior variables were still there.

Answer (score 0):

Fix based on @AdminOfThings comments above. I changed Freespace (GB) to Freespace_GB and used that (and took out the divide in the second test).

```
Write-Host "TEST1" 
 Get-WMIObject  -ComputerName $computers Win32_LogicalDisk `
| select __SERVER, DriveType, VolumeName, Name, @{n='Size (Gb)' ;e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.size/1gb)}},@{n='FreeSpace_GB';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}}, @{n='PercentFree';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.freespace/$_.size*100)}} `
| Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and [decimal]$_.PercentFree -lt [decimal]$thresholdPercentFree } 

Write-Host "TEST2" 
 Get-WMIObject  -ComputerName $computers Win32_LogicalDisk `
| select __SERVER, DriveType, VolumeName, Name, @{n='Size (Gb)' ;e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.size/1gb)}},@{n='FreeSpace_GB';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}}, @{n='PercentFree';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.freespace/$_.size*100)}} `
| Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and [decimal]$_.PercentFree -lt [decimal]$thresholdPercentFree -and [decimal]($_.FreeSpace_Gb) -lt $thresholdFreespaceGB}
```

Comment: On a side note: you should filter the objects before selecting.  That is, use `Where-Object` before `Select-Object`.  That way you will discard any unwanted items before you then generate your custom objects.  For small collections, this will likely make no difference, but if you do this with a very large collection where you only require a small subset, then your current approach will be much less efficient since you are generating huge numbers of objects you then immediately throw away.